# Modify array data in a form within a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

There have a form in a view page that take data as a multidimensional array.In edit mode that form value is fetching and showing data through a foreach loop.
Now my problem is i'm unable to modify that form data in that foreach loop and send it to database. I gone through some posts about foreach key concept but how do I take modified value here in html and send it to database within this foreach loop?
My code fetching data properly but fail to update data.

Here is my code of view page :

```php
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Subscription</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Interval</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    <?php
    if (!empty($invoice_detail)) {
        foreach ($invoice_detail as $key => $result) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="invoice[$key][invoice_detail_subs]" id="invoice_detail_subs"
                           value="<?php echo $result->invoice_detail_subs; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="invoice[$key][invoice_detail_desc]" id="invoice_detail_desc"
                           value="<?php echo $result->invoice_detail_desc; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="invoice[$key][invoice_detail_interval]" id="invoice_detail_interval"
                           value="<?php echo $result->invoice_detail_interval; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="invoice[$key][invoice_detail_amount]" id="invoice_detail_amount"
                           value="<?php echo $result->invoice_detail_amount; ?>"/></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        <?php }
    } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here it is Update code in in controller :

```php
if ($this->input->post('Submit')) {
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT * FROM ".$this->db->dbprefix."invoice_details WHERE invoice_detail_invoie_id ='".$id."' "
    );
    $fetch = $query->row();
    $rows = $query->num_rows();

    if ($id) {


        $data1 = [
            'invoice_detail_subs'     => $this->input->post('invoice_detail_subs'),
            'invoice_detail_desc'     => $this->input->post('invoice_detail_desc'),
            'invoice_detail_interval' => $this->input->post('invoice_detail_interval'),
            'invoice_detail_amount'   => $this->input->post('invoice_detail_amount'),
            'invoice_detail_mddt'     => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        ];

        $this->db->update('invoice_details', $data1, 'invoice_detail_invoie_id = '.$id);


    }
}
```

Comment: _“but how do I take modified value here in html and send it to database within this foreach loop?”_ - what sense would that even make? If you did it in that very same loop, then where-when-how would the user have the ability to change the values? (Or, if you don’t want the user to be able to change the values, but what they should be changed to is determined by script logic - then why output the table with input fields in the first place?)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, what yoy're trying to do is display a form with predefined values and then update the data in the database on submit (so, an update form). I don't know what the value of "invoice[$key][invoice_detail_subs]" is, but it should be "invoice_detail_subs", because PHP uses the name to identify the input field.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to ask clearly.. Yes it's just normal ADD, EDIT form with submit button. BUT I have to do that ADD & EDIT in a same form. In EDIT mode i'm fetching the data within foreach loop. Now i've to modify the values of multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

### View Code

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Subscription</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Interval</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<?php
if (is_object($invoice_detail)) :
    foreach ($invoice_detail as $key => $result) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="invoice_detail_subs"
                       value="<?= $result->invoice_detail_subs; ?>"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="invoice_detail_desc"
                       value="<?= $result->invoice_detail_desc; ?>"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="invoice_detail_interval"
                       value="<?= $result->invoice_detail_interval; ?>"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="invoice_detail_amount"
                       value="<?= $result->invoice_detail_amount; ?>"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach;
endif; ?>

</tbody>
```

### update code in controller

```
    if ($this->input->method()=="post") {
  if ($id) {
   $data1 = ['invoice_detail_subs'=> $this->input->post('invoice_detail_subs'),
   'invoice_detail_desc' => $this->input->post('invoice_detail_desc'),
'invoice_detail_interval' => $this->input->post('invoice_detail_interval'),
'invoice_detail_amount' => $this->input->post('invoice_detail_amount'),
 'invoice_detail_mddt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")];
$this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix."invoice_details", $data1,['invoice_detail_invoie_id'=>$id]);
 }
}
$query = $this->db->select('*')->where(["invoice_detail_invoie_id"=>$id])->get($this->db->dbprefix."invoice_details");
 $fetch = $query->row();
 $rows = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i need to take multiple row value within that foreach loop. That is the problem.

Comment: $fetch = $query->row(); replace it by $fetch = $query->result(); and also change is_object by is_array in view

Comment: A controller should not be performing any database operations -- that is what the model is for.